# Get multiple Span Tags inside the selection of Text in a HTML Page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, html

I needed to get all the element ids within the selection range.

For example,

Start   the work

If i selected the "Start" and "the" together i am only getting element id of "Start" using getelementbyselectionrange in javascript. How to get the array of span id's in the selection sentence.

I am trying this example in uiwebview in iphone, How to achieve this using javascript?

I got the jquery example in this site: http://jsfiddle.net/KC48j/17/ But it is not helping me?

Help me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify "start the work".  I'm not sure based on your description if the HTML of that sentence is:

```
<div id="d1"><span id="s1">start</span><span id="s2">the</span><span id="s3">work</span></div>
```

If that's the case, then you can use YUI's [getElementsBy](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Dom.html#method_getElementsBy) function in it's DOM package and make sure you specify the div id `d1` as the `root` and the `tag` to be `span`.  This will return back an array of span DOM elements within that div that you can loop on.